# VBA macro to Count rows by passing column header at runime

Tags: vba

I wanted to count the number of rows by passing the column header at runtime

I am working on a graph with table fetched from SQL DB and is saved in sheet 2 [from the same workbook, only the data fetched from DB are stored in sheet 2]. The X and Y axis depends on the table and parameters which I wanted to plot. Now by changing the X and Y axis from Sheet 1 correspondingly I wanted the macro to count the corresponding last row in the related column. How could I pass that column header at run time.

I could identify the column header value by using the find option but could not pass the column header value at runtime below is my code for kind evaluation.

```
Dim Col_Header, Col_H, Row_Num As String

Set Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
Cells.Find(What:=Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Range("J5").Value,After:=ActiveCell,LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext,         MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Col_Num = ActiveCell.Address
Col_H = Right(Col_Num, 3)
Col_Num = Col_H
Col_H = Left(Col_Num, 1)
Col_H = "" & Chr(34) & Col_H & Chr(34) & ""

Dim LastRow As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "& col_H &").End(xlUp).Row
        End With
```

Select X and Y axis

[image]

Corresponding data in sheet2

[image]

Thanks
mmaddi4u

Answer (score 0):

Using match will give you a number of sorts, but from the range returned from find you can get the column property and then use cells(row,col) to do what you need to do.  So rngfound=cells.find( etc.  Then rngfound.column.  or match("look for",a1:t1,1,0) on tablet at the minute so cant do exact code.